# Does Task.Factory.FromAsync fire created tasks?

Tags: c#, async-await

I have two tasks `t1` and `t2` that I generate from an old API designed with begin/end async model as follows. However I *strictly* want to run them one after another. (this is Azure Table storage API)

```
Task<DataServiceResponse> t1 = Task.Factory.FromAsync(ctx1.BeginSaveChangesWithRetries(null, null), r => ctx1.EndSaveChangesWithRetries(r));
Task<DataServiceResponse> t2 = Task.Factory.FromAsync(ctx2.BeginSaveChangesWithRetries(null, null),  r => ctx2.EndSaveChangesWithRetries(r));

await t1.ContinueWith(t => t2, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted | TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnCanceled);
```

I read the [`FromAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.fromasync.aspx) documentation but it does not state that these tasks (`t1`&`t2`) are fired or not:

> `FromAsync(IAsyncResult, Action<IAsyncResult>):`
>   Creates a Task that executes an end method action when a specified IAsyncResult completes.

- Does this guarantee `t2` will always be executed **after** successful execution of `t1`?
- I believe this code calls `Begin...` method of the begin/end pair. Usually is the operation (in this case, making HTTP request to Azure Service) done in end method? (I am not quite familiar with what is inside begin/end implementations)
- Does `t1` start (or is it scheduled) before `await` statement (like I use `Task.Factory.StartNew`)?

Comment: What do you mean by your second question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be more explicit than just 'no it won't do what you want' as an answer:

> Does Task.Factory.FromAsync fire created tasks?

yes the `Task` object is fully functional and will do what it was designed to do - wait for already running request to end.

> Does this guarantee t2 will always be executed after successful execution of t1?

No the web requests are already running/out our your control to deffer/order them.

Tasks created by `FormAsync` are not capable of starting on their own. They receive `IAsyncResult` as parameter so you have already started the underlying job/task/web request by calling `BeginSaveChangesWithRetries`. The task here is only a wrapper on this legacy asynchronous mechanism that allows you to await those and write your code in the new and nice way.

To do it the nice way simply write:

```
await Task.Factory.FromAsync(ctx1.BeginSaveChangesWithRetries(null, null), r => ctx1.EndSaveChangesWithRetries(r));
await Task.Factory.FromAsync(ctx2.BeginSaveChangesWithRetries(null, null),  r => ctx2.EndSaveChangesWithRetries(r));
```

If first await throws then second wont be executed.

Comment: This is incorrect, as internally a Task is started but never returned to the caller. Furthermore, the returned Task is created and started by a TaskCompletionSource

Comment: How about now are we in sync now?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the title's question is yes, a new Task is started, as found using Resharper's decompiler and the .NET reference sources, but you never see it.

FromAsync creates an internal detached Task to run the End method synchronously on its TaskScheduler. You never see this task. What you see is a TaskCompletionSource.Task which is signaled when the End method finishes, either normally or by throwing an exception.

Exceptions thrown by the End method are set on the TaskCompletionSource and therefore the Task you wait on.

The Task returned from FromAsync is created by the TaskCompletionSource so you can't say that it is started or not - it can be awaited and signalled when your operation finishes

So:

<s>T2 will run only on sucessful completion</s>

1. T2 is started before you even call the ContinueWith method so T1 and T2 will run in parallel. T2 will be awaited only if T1 succeeds.
2. What happens inside Begin/End depends on the implementation, but generally Begin starts an asynchronous operation and End blocks waiting for the result of this operation. Web service and WebClient calls work this way.
3. T1 starts when you call the Begin method, which happens on the first line

**EDIT**

Things don't change if you call the FromAsync overload that accepts a function instead of an IAsyncResult, as FromAsync calls the function immediatelly and starts the operation

Comment: On second line there is also a call to Begin which will start the second request. So why would this be deferred to end of t1?

Comment: There are 4 questions, one of them on the title. And a new task IS started to wait and process the End method